# Tracking time spent at a location in Android using Google apis

Tags: android, geofencing

I need to track the time spent by the app user at a particular location. Please suggest me an optimized approach. I looked into this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

I can use the above for getting the location, but what should my approach to achieve what I want ?

Comment: you want time in particular point or area ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I want time in particular are.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to fetch current user location at defined interval and if location goes beyond your region, we can calculate time difference

Follow this steps

```
 long time1 = new Date().getTime();
 long time2;

 double firstLat, firstLog;
 // fetch current user location using this link
 // https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

 //Declare the timer
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 //Set the schedule function and rate
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
         // Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)

         double curLat, curLog;

         // fetch current user location using this link
         // https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

         if(!isUserInRegion(firstLat,firstLog,curLat,curLog){
             time2 = new Date().getTime();
             timer.cancel();
             timer.purge();
      }

 },
 //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
 0,
 //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
 1000);
 long timeDiff = time2 - time1;


 private boolean isUserInRegion(double firstLat, double firstLog, double curLat, double curLog){
      int r = 0.005; // Any radious
      double dx = curLat - firstLat;
      double dy = curLog - firstLog;
      return dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r;
 }
```

Hope so this trick works for you :)